# AWS Cloudformation template for AWS::ApiGateway::Resource: How to create dynamic key for RequestParameter?

Tags: amazon-web-services, templates, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, querystringparameter

I am creating a cloudformation nested template that creates an `AWS::ApiGateway::Method`. That method has query strings with names received as parameters from the parent stack something like this:

```
Parameters:
    #...other parameters
    queryStringName:
        Type: String
    queryStringMandatory
        Type: String
        AllowedValues: [true,false]
Resources:
    ApiGatewayMethod:
        Type: 'AWS::ApiGatewayMethod::Method'
        Properties:
        #... other properties
        RequestParameters:
            # here I want to inject somehow the queryStringName into the key definition
            method.request.querystring.{$queryStringName}: !Ref queryStringMandatory #doesnt work
```

The problem is that the current way to define a query string is like this:

```
RequestParameters:
  method.request.querystring.queryStringName: true
```

where true indicates if the query string is mandatory. Using this way the queryString name is in the left part (the key definition part), and you can't use intrinsic functions there or `!Ref`.
Is there something I am missing or is there a workaround for this?

Comment: I am not aware of an 'workaround'. For me this is more a use case for the AWS Cloud Development Kit. You can use standard code, e.g. Python to generate a CloudFormation template dynamically, and aferwards feed i into a deployment step, which is what you like to achieve. Something like a AWS CodePipline creating it for you or and microservice return the correct CF template depending on you needs: https://aws.amazon.com/cdk/resources/